# How to find real subspace of solutions to differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations

I have the following differential equation

$$\sqrt{f(x)}-a \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}+b \frac{1}{x}=c $$

where $a,b,c>0$ and I am interested in the solutions for $x<0$. DSolve gives me an analytic result, but for generic values of the integration constant it is complex. I wonder how I can find out for which values the solutions are real?

```
assumptions = {a > 0, b > 0, c > 0, x < 0};
numbers = {a -> 1, b -> 3, c -> 2, C[1] -> -2};
f[x] /. DSolve[Sqrt[f[x]] - a f'[x]/f[x] + b/x == c, f[x], x, 
Assumptions -> assumptions] // First // FullSimplify
Plot[{Re[%], Im[%]} /. numbers // Evaluate, {x, -10, 0}]
```

The output is

[image]

Comment: $b=2ka, k\in\mathbb N$

Answer (score 5):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

assumptions = {a > 0, b > 0, c > 0, x < 0};
numbers = {a -> 1, b -> 3, c -> 2, C[1] -> -2};

expr1 = f[x] /. 
    DSolve[Sqrt[f[x]] - a f'[x]/f[x] + b/x == c, f[x], x, 
     Assumptions -> assumptions] // First // FullSimplify
```

[image]

The `assumptions` also can be used by [`FullSimplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html). Use an [`Assuming`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html) construct to make the `assumptions` available to all enclosed functions.

```
expr2 = Assuming[assumptions, 
  f[x] /. DSolve[Sqrt[f[x]] - a f'[x]/f[x] + b/x == c, f[x], x] // First // 
   FullSimplify]
```

[image]

Use [`FunctionDomain`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionDomain.html) to determine the conditions for the expression to be real.

```
Assuming[assumptions,
 FunctionDomain[expr2, x] // FullSimplify]
```

[image]